# How to move row to another Section while clicking on row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have Implemented multi select row but what i have to do is when we click on row it will move on another section , Here's my code what i have tried is ?

can anyone help me out from this ? Thanks in advance ...

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     return 2; //assuming you have only two sections
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     if (section == 0)
        return self.firstSectionDataSource.count;
     else if (section == 1)
        return self.dataArray.count;
     else
        return 0;
 }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Here, Have to move row to another section while clcking ..

      // other multiselect code
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Configure a cell to show the corresponding string from the array.
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
 {

   @try {

    NSMutableArray *sourceArray = nil;
    if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0) {
        sourceArray = self.firstSectionDataSource;
    }
    else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1)
    {
        sourceArray = self.dataArray;
    }


    NSMutableArray *destinationArray = nil;
    if  (destinationIndexPath.section == 0) {
        destinationArray = self.firstSectionDataSource;
    }
    else if (destinationIndexPath.section == 1)
    {
        destinationArray = self.dataArray;
    }


    NSString *stringToMov = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [sourceArray removeObject:stringToMov];
    [destinationArray insertObject:stringToMov atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"exception = %@ \n reason = %@",exception,exception.reason);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you please explain in brief ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell setShowsReorderControl:YES];
```

And you need to implement the following `UITableView` delegate and data source methods properly

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //assuming you have only two sections
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return firstSectionDataSource.count;
    else if (section == 1)
        return secondSectionDataSource.count;
    else
        return 0;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

    @try {

        NSMutableArray *sourceArray = nil;
        if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0) {
            sourceArray = firstSectionDataSource;
        }
        else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1)
        {
            sourceArray = secondSectionDataSource;
        }


        NSMutableArray *destinationArray = nil;
        if  (destinationIndexPath.section == 0) {
            destinationArray = firstSectionDataSource;
        }
        else if (destinationIndexPath.section == 1)
        {
            destinationArray = secondSectionDataSource;
        }


        NSString *stringToMov = [[sourceArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] retain];
        [sourceArray removeObject:stringToMov];
        [destinationArray insertObject:stringToMov atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        [stringToMov release];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception = %@ \n reason = %@",exception,exception.reason);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...check out  i have updated my question as per your code but what i have to do is while clicking on cell it will move on another section ...for example in section 0 .. it has 0 items when i click on row then it will move to section 0

Comment: First read some documentation about `UITableView`, You are doing it wrong in `cellForRow`, What the structure of your data source, do you have two different arrays for two sections ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];

    // other multiselect code
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps me a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"d",@"e",@"f", nil], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstSection",@"secondsection", nil]];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return [[dict allKeys] count]; //assuming you have only two sections
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[dict objectForKey:[dict allKeys][section]] count];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [dict objectForKey:[dict allKeys][indexPath.section]];
    NSString *str = arr[indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row!=0) {
        [arr removeObject:str];
    }

    NSMutableArray *arr1 = [dict objectForKey:[dict allKeys][0]];
    [arr1 addObject:str];
    [tableView reloadData];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *arr = [dict objectForKey:[dict allKeys][indexPath.section]];
    NSString *str = arr[indexPath.row];

    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    cell.textLabel.text = str;

    return cell;
}
```